# Multiply string in column by how often it occurs in the corpus

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using character n-grams to detect a language, right now i mapped out all nouns and put them in a Pandas Dataframe.

right now i've got this :

`word1=df['lemmastring1'][0]*df['count'][0]`

How can i Iterrate this to get it for my whole Dataframe.

[Picture of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrBJW.png)

[This is how i want it for all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXuTE.png)

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data to work with? It will make it much easier to directly assist you with your code as oppose to only theory based answers.

Comment: if `lemmastring1` and `count` values are always in the same row, you can just multiply the columns: `df['lemmastring1']*df['count']`. But it's difficult to say without a small dataframe to see the data

Comment: I added the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
    string  count
0  _jarr_-    500
1  _mens_-    200
```

Doing:

```
df['string']*df['count']
```

Output:

```
0    _jarr_-_jarr_-_jarr_-_jarr_-_jarr_-_jarr_-_jar...
1    _mens_-_mens_-_mens_-_mens_-_mens_-_mens_-_men...
dtype: object
```